# Timeout in local Nuget server

Tags: server, timeout, nuget

I setup a local Nuget server to host companies own packages. (As described here https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/hosting-packages/nuget.server)

It worked fine for months. Then the number of versions of a certain package exceeded 100 and we started having problems while querying available packages in our software.

We use following code piece to query available packages in our software:

```
IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(_NuGetRepositoryURL);
IEnumerable<IPackage> packages = repo.FindPackagesById(packageID);
```

GetVersionsOfPackage waits only couple of seconds before throwing "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found".

It looks like a timeout issue but I couldn't find a timeout parameter nor at the client neither at the server.